# Hibernate throwing unique constriant exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to insert records into the databse using the following code, records are obtained from a csv file then stored into referenceTableList. for files having records less than 200 the code works fine but is throwing "Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert" for more than 200 records

```
 try {
            if (referenceTableList != null && referenceTableList.size() > 0) {
                Iterator iterator = referenceTableList.iterator();
                int count=0;
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    this.getHibernateSession().save(iterator.next());
                    count++;
                    if(count % 150 == 0)
                    {
                        this.getHibernateSession().flush();
                        this.getHibernateSession().clear();
                    }

                }
            }
            //this.getHibernateSession().flush();
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            String msg = "Duplicate product code entered = "
                    + referenceTableList;
            BuUtil.info(LOG, msg);

            throw new BuDataAccessException(msg, e);
```

this is the Stack trace

```
10:08:20,576 ERROR [AbstractFlushingEventListener] Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.bu.app.bha.dataaccess.dataobject.managereference.OccupationClassificationDO]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2271)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2664)
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at com.bu.framework.dataaccess.hibernate.jta.JTASessionSynchronization.closeSession(JTASessionSynchronization.java:78)
        at com.bu.framework.dataaccess.hibernate.jta.JTASessionSynchronization.beforeCompletion(JTASessionSynchronization.java:68)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:114)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:247)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:86)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.end(AtomicAction.java:216)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commit(TransactionImple.java:238)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.endTransaction(TxInterceptorCMT.java:501)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:361)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:181)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:168)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138)
        at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:648)
        at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:960)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.InvocationHandlerEJB21.invoke(InvocationHandlerEJB21.java:147)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServiceEndpointInvoker.invoke(ServiceEndpointInvoker.java:220)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:422)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:286)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:196)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:122)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet.service(EndpointServlet.java:84)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (AOBHA.SYS_C008063) violated

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10500)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeBatch(WrappedStatement.java:620)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.addToBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:34)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2251)
        ... 57 more
10:08:20,576 ERROR [JTASessionSynchronization] Unable to close Hibernate Session during completion of JTA Transaction. Will attempt to rollback transaction.
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.bu.app.bha.dataaccess.dataobject.managereference.OccupationClassificationDO]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2271)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2664)
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at com.bu.framework.dataaccess.hibernate.jta.JTASessionSynchronization.closeSession(JTASessionSynchronization.java:78)
        at com.bu.framework.dataaccess.hibernate.jta.JTASessionSynchronization.beforeCompletion(JTASessionSynchronization.java:68)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:114)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:247)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:86)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.end(AtomicAction.java:216)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commit(TransactionImple.java:238)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.endTransaction(TxInterceptorCMT.java:501)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:361)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:181)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:168)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138)
        at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:648)
        at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:960)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.InvocationHandlerEJB21.invoke(InvocationHandlerEJB21.java:147)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServiceEndpointInvoker.invoke(ServiceEndpointInvoker.java:220)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:422)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:286)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:196)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:122)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet.service(EndpointServlet.java:84)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Hibernate mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping
>
    <class
        name="com.bu.app.bha.dataaccess.dataobject.managereference.OccupationClassificationDO"
        table="BHA_OCC_CLASS"
    >

        <id
            name="occupationClassificationId"
            column="OCCCLA_ID"
            type="java.lang.Long"
            unsaved-value="null"
        >
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">BHA_OCC_CLASS_S</param>
              <!--  
                  To add non XDoclet generator parameters, create a file named 
                  hibernate-generator-params-OccupationClassificationDO.xml 
                  containing the additional parameters and place it in your merge dir. 
              --> 
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property
            name="description"
            type="java.lang.String"
            update="true"
            insert="true"
            column="DESCRIPTION"
            not-null="true"
        />

        <property
            name="effectiveDate"
            type="java.util.Date"
            update="true"
            insert="true"
            column="EFFECTIVE_DATE"
            not-null="true"
        />

        <property
            name="grouping"
            type="java.lang.String"
            update="true"
            insert="true"
            column="GROUPING"
            not-null="true"
        />

        <property
            name="verified"
            type="java.lang.Boolean"
            update="true"
            insert="true"
            column="VERIFIED"
        />

        <many-to-one
            name="productDO"
            class="com.bu.app.bha.dataaccess.dataobject.managereference.ProductDO"
            cascade="none"
            outer-join="auto"
            update="true"
            insert="true"
            column="PROD_ID"
        />

        <!--
            To add non XDoclet property mappings, create a file named
                hibernate-properties-OccupationClassificationDO.xml
            containing the additional properties and place it in your merge dir.
        -->

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

DO class primary key getter setter

```
/**
     * Set the simple primary key value that identifies this object.
     * 
     * @param oOccupationClassificationId
     *            The occupationClassificationId to set.
     */
    public void setOccupationClassificationId(Long oOccupationClassificationId) {
        this.occupationClassificationId = oOccupationClassificationId;
    }

    /**
     * Return the simple primary key value that identifies this object.
     *
     * @return Returns the occupationClassificationId.
     *
     * @hibernate.id column = "OCCCLA_ID" unsaved-value = "null"
     * @hibernate.id generator-class = "sequence"
     * @hibernate.generator-param name = "sequence" value = "BHA_OCC_CLASS_S"
     */
    public Long getOccupationClassificationId() {
        return this.occupationClassificationId;
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your Entity and its configuration?

Comment: hibernate mapping and DO shared above.

Comment: @Amit did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Rohit no still looking for the reason.

Comment: Can you share your sequence DDL statement?